# Plotting the relation between two columns using matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i have two columns in my data-frame. one of the columns in date format. The other column has 1's and 0's . i want to plot a graph showing the relation between the two columns.Here is a little snippet of my data

```
Date received   Consumer disputed?
15-05-2014  0
18-09-2014  0
13-03-2014  0
17-07-2015  1
20-11-2014  0
26-06-2014  0
28-09-2012  0
06-05-2015  1
25-02-2013  0
30-03-2016  0
21-03-2014  0
```

The plot should be such that the distribution of 1's and 0's with respect to date specially the month part so that i can decide which month has more 1's and which have more 0's. Thanks in advance

Comment: If a month doesn't appear, does that imply the value is 0?

Comment: No the month appears in every row. lets say The 1's and 0's are randomly distributed.. more 1's  on some months and less on some other. using the plot i need to decide which part of the year has more consumer dispute (1 is for yes . 0 is for no in consumer dispute column)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a bar chart

```
df['Consumer disputed?'].groupby(df['Date received'].dt.month).sum().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use the jointplot from Seaborn

```
data['month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']).dt.month
sns.jointplot(x='Consumer',y='month',data=data)]
```

[image]

Comment: its not working. Showing error "ValueError: First argument must be a sequence"

Comment: Can you check the datatypes of the columns and make sure it is int64?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of ...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
x = df['Date'].values
y = df['received'].values
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution to my problem.

```
#extract the month form the date

train_data['month'] = pd.to_datetime(train_data['Date received']).dt.month

#crosstab displays the frequency distribution of the variable
#(here "Consumer  disputed?") in a matrix format` 
b = pd.crosstab(train_data['month'], train_data['Consumer disputed?'])


#transform the label month into a column
b.reset_index(level='month', inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
#plot the graph
b.plot('month', 'Yes')
```

[image]